# Plotting multiple series with different x-coordinates using ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have two data frames, data1 and data2, containing measurements of var1 and var2, respectively, for positions 1-100 of ~2000 genes.

Example of data format:

```
Gene Name   X1-var1    X2-var1    X3-var1   ...   X100-var1
Gene1       0.5        0.3        0.2             0.9
Gene2       1.1        0.6        0.3             2.5
Gene3       4.5        2.0        9.8             1.2    
...
Gene2000    0.7        2.3        3.9       ...   0.8
```

Previously, I plotted var1 for data1 vs. position using ggplot, with each of the genes being marked in a different color (series):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
genes <- data.frame(x=seq(1,100), t(data1))
genes.melted <- melt(genes,id="x")
ggplot(data=genes.melted, aes(x=x,y=value,color=variable))+geom_line()
```

Now, I would like to plot var1 vs. var2, with the var1-var2 pairing determined by the position and gene, and use the original position information to determine the color (neglecting the gene information). 
That is, I would like to plot points

```
(X1-var1 for Gene1, X1-var2 for Gene1),(X1-var1 for Gene2, X1-var2 for Gene2),(X1-var1 for Gene3, X1-var2 for Gene3),..., (X1-var1 for Gene2000, X1-var2 for Gene2000)
```

in one color, and

```
(X2-var1 for Gene1, X2-var2 for Gene1),(X2-var1 for Gene2, X2-var2 for Gene2),(X2-var1 for Gene3, X2-var2 for Gene3),..., (X2-var2 for Gene2000, X2-var2 for Gene2000)
```

in another color, and so on.
I am confused about how to do this when my x variables will not be the same for each group - previously, when I plotted versus position, the x-variables remained the same.

Comment: Never mind. I'm with you...Should be doable. FYI, you can use `inherit.aes = FALSE` to block the inheritance of an aes in ggplot in, say, a secondary `geom_line()` -- which may be useful here.

Comment: @InNoam, thanks for your suggestion. Looking again at the problem with fresh eyes, I realized that I had stated one problem in words and described another using variables, but I think your hint will be applicable either way.